# Flutter Image is always Grey instead of original Colors

Tags: flutter

The image is always grey (tried multiple testimages). Size is displaying and its form/outline, but its all Grey instead of the colors in the image used.

class:

```
class _Language extends State<Language> {  
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return const ListTile(
      leading: Icon(Icons.language),
      title: Text('Language'),
      trailing:
          ImageIcon(AssetImage("assets/test.png"), size: 26));
  }
}
```

pubspec:

```
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - assets/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the expected behaviour of ImageIcon class.
Please, check the links below.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ImageIcon-class.html
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/81643

Comment: But how can i use Image.asset then in a ListTile its always showing me an Error if i try that.

Comment: Image.asset should work fine. Could you describe the error?

Comment: Fixed it. Image.asset worked fine in the moment i removed "const" at ListTile.